# How can i show data of a username (with same role) - APEX

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracleapplications

I am using Apex Application, I need to show data depending on the username that is logged in. I have created roles, but I want to only show the data depending on the patient. For example: A patient wants to see his personal data and not all the data of other patients, is this possible to do with PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable APP_USER for that. It contains the username of the logged on user. If the page is public then APP_USER will have value "nobody".
Example:

```
SELECT <columns> 
  FROM <table> 
 WHERE username = :APP_USER;
```

Note that for sensitive data you might want to look at more robust ways of security your data, like VPD. That also can be used with apex.
Rgds
Koen